# How do I reset safari to a state equal to that of a new user?

Tags: macos, safari

There is a website (happening.im) which does not work in my user account, but does work when I switch to the guest user.
So the problem is in my user profile somehow.

I've tried deleting ~/Library/Safari but that didn't do the trick.

How do I completely reset safari to the state that the guest user has?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing. Oddly enough it isn't there anymore in Safari for O/S X 10.10.3 (Safari 8.0.6). One wonders if the "Clear history and website data..." option will do the same thing if you then select "everything" in the subsequent pop-up menu.

Comment: No, 'Clear history and website data' is not the reset I need. I'm afraid I'll have to create a new user account and start using that in order to get my safari running the way I need it to... But that's a lot of work. There must be a way to reset safari to the state it has when a new user is created.

Answer (score 1):

This website has a list of steps you could take:
http://www.macissues.com/2015/06/22/how-to-fully-reset-safari-on-your-mac/

Answer (score 1):

If you have already deleted or pulled the ~/Library/Safari folder into the Trash, and the issue is still occurring, the truly best option you can take is to boot the computer into Recovery mode and reinstall your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Open Safari. Click Safari in the top left, and in the drop-down list, click Reset Safari.

Comment: There is no Reset Safari. Preferences & Clear History & Website are it.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to find help with the same problem. I went into the guest user profile and copied the preference information from there to my profile.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This doesn't seem to be an answer, and should probably be a comment or new question altogether. I know you don't have the points required yet to comment, but I've asked someone to come take a look who can move it. In the mean time, go ahead and see if you can garner the points necessary.